# Getting response from action method into jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My jquery for onclick,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitSave").on("click", function () {
        var confirmPassword = $("#txtLgnPasswordConfirmReset").val();
        var passwordReset = {
            UserName: $("#txtLgnUsername").val(),
            Password: $("#hdnOldPassword").val(),
            NewPassword: $("#txtLgnPasswordReset").val()
        }
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Account/PasswordReset",
                data: passwordReset                    
            });
       });
   });
```

Below is my Controller action method which is called on 'ON CLICK' by above jquery,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PasswordReset(User user)
{
    if (_lfAPI.PasswordReset(user))
    {
        return RedirectToRoute(Constants.Login);
    }
    return View();
}
```

If my, if(condition) in the above method returns true, I want to show a notify message...
My notify message,

```
notifyMessage.showNotifyMessage('info', 'Your password has been reset.Please login with your new password.', false)
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK)` for an OK result, `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);` for a failed result. Then you can hook onto `$.ajax().done()` & `.fail()`

Answer (score 2):

you can handle this in ajax success callback as

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/Account/PasswordReset",
  data: passwordReset,
  success: function(data) {
    if (data == true) {
      //show success msg
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: yeah you can use this if you have only boolean return from your service

Comment: try this
var data = 'false';
if(data == true) alert('here1');
if(data == 'true') alert('here2');
if(data) alert('here3')
you will get an idea

Comment: Interesting thing with `"false" == true` (and `"false" == false` also returns `false`, by the way) thanks. This is what happens when you work with weakly typed languages...

Answer (score 0):

Use success callback in your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Account/PasswordReset",
    data: passwordReset  ,
    success: function (resp) {
        if (resp == "true") {
            // do your stuff here
            notifyMessage.showNotifyMessage('info', 'Your password has been reset.Please login with your new password.', false)
        } 
    },                  
});
});
```